# Вывод ошибки при неправильном логине/пароле через json

Tags: php, jquery, json

есть форма авторизации который обращается к файлу auth.php, он в свою очередь к серверу, если юзер вводит неправильно логин и пароль, то ничего не происходит. Не могу разобраться как вытащить ошибку что пароль логин не верен.
при неправильном пароле логине выдает ошибку:

```
VM727:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success ((index):78)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

сам скрипт jquery

```
 <script>
        jQuery(function() {
            $("#myForm1").submit(function() {
                var formData = {
                     "Name":$("#Name").val()
                      , "Pwd":$("#Pwd").val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url:'auth.php'
                    , type:'POST'
                    , data: JSON.stringify(formData)
                    , success: function (data) {

             result=JSON.parse(data);
             console.log(result);
             if (result.hasOwnProperty("error")){
                  alert('Не верный логин или пароль');
             }else{
                window.location.href = "main.php?sid=" +result.Sid +"&isn=" +result.isn +"&pDeptISN=2709";
                //console.log(result);
             }


                          // Функция обработчик.
            }

                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Вот сам файл auth.php

```
<?php
$myCurl = curl_init();
$rawdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$params =json_decode($rawdata);  

$Name =$params->Name; 
$Pwd =$params->Pwd; 
$password = hash('sha512', $Pwd);

$data_string='';

$data_string = $data_string . '<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins="http://*****.ru/">';
$data_string = $data_string . '<x:Header/>';
$data_string = $data_string . '<x:Body>';
$data_string = $data_string . '<ins:ExecProc>';
$data_string = $data_string . '<ins:pData>';
$data_string = $data_string . '<![CDATA[';
$data_string = $data_string . '<data>';
$data_string = $data_string . '<request>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<RequestIp>192.168.5.34</RequestIp>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<AppId>1531991</AppId>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<reqName>Auth</reqName>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '<params>';
        $data_string = $data_string . ' <Name>' . $Name .'</Name>';
        $data_string = $data_string . ' <Pwd>'  . $password . '</Pwd>';
    $data_string = $data_string . '</params>';
$data_string = $data_string . '</request>';
$data_string = $data_string . '</data>';
$data_string = $data_string . ']]>';
$data_string = $data_string . '</ins:pData>';
$data_string = $data_string . '</ins:ExecProc>';
$data_string = $data_string . '</x:Body>';
$data_string = $data_string . '</x:Envelope>';

//echo $data_string;


//echo "\n\n";

curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(

    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://site.ru/webservice/Svc.asmx',
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST=> "POST",  
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',                                                                                
    'SOAPAction: http://*****.ru/ExecProc',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
    CURLOPT_POST => true
)); 
$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);

$xml=simplexml_load_string ($response, NULL, NULL, "http://*****.ru/");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("md", "http://*****.ru/"); 
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"); 
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); 
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

$soapResult =$xml->xpath('//md:ExecProcResult//data');

//var_dump($soapResult[0]);
$sid =$soapResult[0]->result->Sid->__toString();
$isn =$soapResult[0]->result->UserDetails->ISN->__toString();

if(count($soapResult)>0){
    if(!isset($soapResult[0]->error)){
        echo json_encode(array("Sid"=>$sid, "isn"=>$isn));
    }
}else{
    echo json_encode(array("error"=>"Не понятная ошибка"));
}

?>
```

Comment: в общем вывел через try catch

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
    try {

   .....
    if (isset($soapResult[0]->error)) {
        throw new Exception($soapResult[0]->error->text);
    }
    $sid =$soapResult[0]->result->Sid->__toString();
    $isn =$soapResult[0]->result->UserDetails->ISN->__toString();

    if(count($soapResult)>0){
        if(!isset($soapResult[0]->error)){
            echo json_encode(array("Sid"=>$sid, "isn"=>$isn));
            die();
        }else{
           throw new Exception("Не понятная ошибка");
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Не понятная ошибка");

    } catch(Exception $e) { 
        echo json_encode(array("error"=>$e->getMessage()));
    }

    ?>
```

весь код получился таким